# Не работает команда создания файла в docker через make

Tags: docker, makefile

На ПК с windows 8.1 установлен Docker Toolbox.
При вводе команды в терминале phpstorm-а она отрабатывает успешно и файл создаётс

```
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/5_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
```

Если эту же самую команду поместить в Makefile и запустить `make manager-ready`

```
manager-ready:
    docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/5_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
```

она отрабатывает с ошибкой (другие make команды работают нормально, проблема лишь с этой командой):

```
D:\work\5_project-manager>make manager-ready
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/5_project-manager/manager:/app --workdir=/app alpine touch .ready
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/msys64/app' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
make: *** [Makefile:43: manager-ready] Error 125
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: вероятно, команда в этих двух случаях интерпретируется двумя разными оболочками.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть параметры в кавычки так, что бы, например, вместо `--workdir=/app` стало `--workdir="/app"`